# Srtipe cause android studio gradle error

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, stripe-payments, payment

I have these dependencies in my Gradle and when I sync the project the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` gives me and error that says it not compatible with the other libraries. when I upgrade to the new ones like prompted I still get the error that they are not compatible

newer version of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` than 24.2.1 is available: 25.3.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This detector looks for usages of libraries where the version you are using is not the current stable release. Using older versions is fine, and there are cases where you deliberately want to stick with an older version. However, you may simply not be aware that a more recent version is available, and that is what this lint check helps find

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.1'
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get when upgrading to the latest support library version?

Comment: @Egor no worries I fixed it XD. just had to change the compileSDKVERSION to 25 and the target sdk to 25 as well